# why Ubuntu 12.10 returns a "network is unreachable" no matter what IP I Ping after I edited the hosts file?

Tags: networking, hosts

The problem is related to the network config settings in Ubuntu.
I edit my hosts file, and now I can't load any sites except those IP(IPv6) included in hosts file.
I try to Ping some IP(both IPv4 and IPv6) in the terminal, but it shows that " Network is unreachable".
Or can somebody simply tell how to restore hosts file in Ubuntu. P.S I don't have a backup.

Answer (score 0):

Below are the original contents of the hosts file, as shown in the image below:

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
127.0.1.1 ubuntu

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1 ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

[image]